# Buena practica uso de mediaQueries con SASS

Tags: css, css3, responsive, sass, mediaqueries

estoy empezando a programar con SASS y me pregunto:

¿Que es mejor practica, definir las media queries anidadas dentro de los selectores o reservar un apartado  del scss exclusivo para volver a definir de nuevo todo el "mapa de estilos"?

Cualquier información adicional o sugerencia es bienvenida. Gracias!

Comment: Ya que la pregunta es bastante basada en opiniones es posible que sea cerrada... La mia es que si lo haces dentro de cada selector que necesitas repetiras el media query mas veces que hacerlo una sola vez con solo los estilos que necesitas modificar; yo elijo siempre la 2da; primero estilos base; y luego en mediaquery solo los necesarios que cambiar

Comment: yo soy de separar el código, el css base, si tengo variables en otro archivo y cosas así. Pero trato de tener una  sección aparte en donde implemento las mediaQueries, el "código" queda más ordenado y como dice @IvanS95, así evitas andar anidando y repitiendo código

Answer (score 1):

en mi opinión es intentar dejarlo lo más completo posible, para que los MediaQuerys sean más fácil de hacer.
Con SASS que teóricamente también es SCSS, al hacer un media querys que sólo cambies las cosas que necesitas, las que son necesarias y no todo.
En éste caso si van a haber cosas vacías, pero a lo cuál llegará a la ruta.

Ejemplo:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .divVacio {
    .divConEstilos {
       display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos.

Comment: se te agradece la intención de apoyo, pero aparte de que la pregunta parece basada en opiniones, la zona de respuestas no es espacio para dar opiniones o recomendaciones; por favor lee [answer]